# 'Python.h' file not found on virtualenv in macOS

Tags: python, django, macos, virtualenv, pipenv

I use macOS Monterey 12.4 as my OS, and I'm trying to install django inside of a virtual environment created with pipenv.

If I run the command `pipenv shell` to create a new virtualenv, then `pipenv install django`, I get this output:

```
Installing django...
Error:  An error occurred while installing django!
Error text: Collecting django
  Using cached Django-4.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.1 MB)
Collecting sqlparse>=0.2.2
  Using cached sqlparse-0.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Collecting backports.zoneinfo
  Using cached backports.zoneinfo-0.2.1.tar.gz (74 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Collecting asgiref<4,>=3.5.2
  Using cached asgiref-3.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: backports.zoneinfo
  Building wheel for backports.zoneinfo (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for backports.zoneinfo (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
Failed to build backports.zoneinfo

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for backports.zoneinfo (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [43 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports
      copying src/backports/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_common.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_zoneinfo.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/_tzpath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      running egg_info
      writing src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      /private/var/folders/3_/gmcg3yrd7d3d7q4vfw0jyqkm0000gn/T/pip-build-env-dez90weq/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:508: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
        warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
      warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'docs'
      warning: no files found matching '*.svg' under directory 'docs'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_output'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      adding license file 'licenses/LICENSE_APACHE'
      writing manifest file 'src/backports.zoneinfo.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      copying src/backports/zoneinfo/py.typed -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/backports/zoneinfo
      warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
      
      running build_ext
      building 'backports.zoneinfo._czoneinfo' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/lib
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -I/Users/samuelebonini/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-TUqHKsfh/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -c lib/zoneinfo_module.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-arm64-cpython-38/lib/zoneinfo_module.o -std=c99
      lib/zoneinfo_module.c:1:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
      #include "Python.h"
               ^~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for backports.zoneinfo
ERROR: Could not build wheels for backports.zoneinfo, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

✘ Installation Failed
```

This is the Pipefile for the environment

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

I have other virtualenvs on the same host machine and they work fine, but creating a new environment always leads to this error (I tried multiple times).

I do have python installed on my machine, as I can run `python3` on a terminal just fine.

What could be causing this?

Comment: I don't know how it works on Mac but on Linux it would need to install package `python-dev` or `python3-dev` to get `Python.h` (C/C++ header). On Linux Ubuntu/Mint it needs `apt`, not `pip` - `apt install python3-dev`. On other Linux it needs other package manager. Maybe Mac needs to use `brew` for this.

Comment: I installed python-dev with brew, but that did not fix the issue

Comment: there can be many different version `-dev` for different version of Python. On Linux I have  `python-dev` `python3-dev` `python3.8-dev` `python3.9-dev` `python3.10-dev` `python3.11-dev` and it needs to install correct version. Other question is if you get EXACTLY the same issue. It may look similar but it may show problem with different element.